# LIBSSL Static lib Compiling issue with fpic

Tags: c++, ssl, makefile

I compiled libssl using

```
CC="gcc34 -fPIC" CXX="g++34 -fPIC" CFLAGS="-m64 -fPIC" ./config --prefix=/workspace/libs/gcc34/64/ssl shared  && make clean && make && make install
```

but when I try to link this static generated library with my dynamic library 
 I am getting

```
 relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against `OPENSSL_cpuid_setup' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

I had given fpic option what is wrong there ?

Comment: I doubt very much that you have to override any compiler flags when building a well packaged library. Have you tried a clean `./configure` plus `make`?

Comment: @Kerrek SB I want to compile libssl static lib with -fpic option

Comment: Check the `./configure --help` options, maybe there's an `--enable-static` or something like that that you missed. I'd be really surprised if you had to override any fundamental options like PIC...

Comment: @Kerrek SB library is compiling successfully but I am getting that error while linking this static lib inside by dynamic library.

Comment: Oh, I see - you want to make a shared library which is statically linked against SSL? This sort of information would have been good to put in the question! Interesting, I don't know, maybe you can pass additional flags to configure so that the static library can be built with PIC...

Comment: @Vivek: I believe you also need to compile libcrypto with `-fPIC`. [This thread](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=246928) might shed some light.

Comment: @jweyrich  how I can tell that in configure ? does I need to give different parameters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're recommendations to use `-Wl,-Bsymbolic` to fix this error.

https://openssl-dev.openssl.narkive.com/uAKes0jM/openssl-org-1521-bug-report

http://www.opensubscriber.com/message/openssl-users@openssl.org/1901249.html

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me, openssl-1.0.1c

```
./config -fPIC
make
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I think, I found the solution: 
This "R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC" happens when LDFLAGS are set with hardening and CFLAGS not.
In your case you shouldn't set CFLAGS I guess .

Reference: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1304277